# R graphics engine version 14 is not supported by this version of RStudio

Tags: r, windows, plot, installation, rstudio

I have installed R version 4.1.2 (2021-11-01) and I get the following message:

"R graphics engine version 14 is not supported by this version of RStudio. The Plots tab will be disabled until a newer version of RStudio is installed."

Is there any way to solve it other than uninstalling R and reinstalling it?

Thanks

Comment: What version of RSudio are you using? R and RStudio are two separate programs. If you updated R, you should probably update RStudio as well.

Comment: I just installed the version: RStudio 2021.09.1 Build 372  . The warning message is no longer displayed, but the Plots tab still does not work.

Comment: So if you type `plot(1:2, 1:2)` in the console then nothing appears in the plot tab? Or does the problem only occur with a particular plot? It's very hard to guess what's going on without further details.

Comment: If I type plot(1:2, 1:2) in the console it does appear in the plot tab. When it does not appear is when I generate a file that has a drawing, of type  exams2pdf("ProbabilidadBarras2MenosVA", encoding = "utf8")
Before it did. In fact, I have installed an older version on another computer and it works perfectly.

Comment: Well I have no idea what that function does or where it is from. Perhaps the package was updated to just create a pdf and not go to a plotting device. It’s hard to say without some sort of reproducible example.

Comment: It is now working properly. The image name was missing in the file so that the image could be seen in the plots tab.
In short, it is as you said. You have to update R and Rstudio separately, because they are different programs. Thank you very much.